# DateTime Always Changed To TimeStamp In Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When trying to add new entity that contains date-Time attributes Like :

```
public DateTime CREATION_DATE { get; set; }
```

then exec add-migration command the migration file change the type  from date/datetime to TimeStamp
Why This happen and how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you care? c# currently has no dateonly or timeonly data types, so the migration tool will just create a timestamp (which has both date and time) from a c# datetime. - DateOnly and TimeOnly will be included in .net 6 - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6 and starting from there a migration code will be able to automagically create a date column datatype of a c# dateonly. - you can override the default behaviour if you like to eg. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumntype-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every database provider has a default mapping of .NET types to database types.  You can override this by decorating the entity property with a [ColumnAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute?view=net-5.0), or using the [HasColumnType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascolumntype?view=efcore-5.0#:%7E:text=Entity%20Framework%20Core%205.0%20and%20other%20versions%20HasColumnType,complete%20type%20name%2C%20including%20precision%2C%20scale%2C%20length%2C%20etc.) fluent property configuration.